Power analysis for ANCOVA
I'm interested in conducting power analysis for experiment design and inference using ANCOVA. I see questions A,B,C vary in terms of quality, applicably and answers; whereas I'm interested in an authoritative, generalizable answer.
Suppose that you're designing an experiment to evaluate a KPI lift due to a treatment. When assuming a 2-sample 2-sided T-test, power analysis indicates that given your sample size, the MDE is 5% greater than the existing sample mean. To use a baseball analogy, that's a home run! But your team just needs to get a batter on base; ideally, you could detect an effect much smaller.
Enter ANCOVA, you essentially just use OLS regression to infer the coefficients for each covariate as well as the treatment indicator variable, then ask the linear model, how would treatment and control groups differ if both were identical in terms of covariates, isolating the effect of treatment? This procedure reduces variance; great! But naturally leaders in your organization will want to know in terms of power and by how much?
From what I've pieced together, an OLS model is still used. However, you cannot condition on treatment exposure because exposure has not yet been administered. So it's simply a matter of the independent variable and its covariates.
I understand to predictive interval to be the 95% (or x%) confidence interval distributed around model predictions given the standard error of linear model residuals.
It's my understanding that when the question is, "what is my power given these covariates and an intention to use ANCOVA?" The mean (0) and residual standard error from the predictive interval can be used for purposes of power analysis.
Is this understanding correct? If not, how in practice might one compute the power of an experimental design where the covariates have already been identified and ANCOVA is the intended inference algorithm?


how in practice might one compute the power of an experimental design where the covariates have already been identified and ANCOVA is the intended inference algorithm?

First, let's discuss equations for statistical power using OLS.  According to Regression Methods in Biostatistics by Vittinghoff, Gidden, Shiboski, and McCulloch, the equation for the number of samples required to achieve statistical power $\gamma$ is provided by
$$ n=\frac{\left(z_{1-\alpha / 2}+z_\gamma\right)^2 \sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}^2}{\left(\beta_j^a \sigma_{x_j}\right)^2\left(1-\rho_j^2\right)}$$
(see the end of the Linear Regression chapter.  Page 130 in the second edition).  Here

$n$ is the total sample size required to achieve the desired statistical power
$z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $1-\alpha/2$ quantile of a standard normal random variable.  If you use $\alpha = 0.05$ then $z_{1-\alpha/2}\approx 1.96$
$z_\gamma$ is the $\gamma$ quantile of a standard normal random variable.  If you use $\gamma = 0.8$ (80% power) then $z_{\gamma}\approx 0.84$
$\sigma^2_{y\mid X}$ is the residual variance in $y$ having adjusted for $X$.  We will return to this.
$\beta$ is the assumed estimated treatment effect.  Remember, we make an assumption of how big this will be (or alternatively determine our MDE given our sample size).
$\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation in the treatment indicator, and
$(1-\rho^2_j)$ is the variance inflation factor.

We can rearrange this equation with some algebra to yield the power given the sample size $n$ and other parameters.  Such an algebraic manipulation yields
$$\gamma=1-\Phi\left[z_{1-\alpha / 2}-\left|\beta_j^a\right| \sigma_{x_j} \sqrt{n\left(1-\rho_j^2\right)} / \sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}\right]$$
Here, $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal random variable.  If the treatment is randomly assigned, we use standard $\alpha$ and $\gamma% values,  and the propensity score for all subjects is 0.5 (i.e probability of being in treatment is 50%) then this equation greatly simplifies to approximately
$$ \gamma = 1 - \Phi\left[ 1.96 - \vert \beta \vert \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2 \sigma_{y\mid X}} \right] \>.$$
This is because under randomization $\rho=0$ and $\sigma_x = 0.5$.
So this equation gives you the power you achieve provided the sample size you plan to achieve and an MDE.  However, there is still the issue of $\sigma_{y\mid X}$. From your bounty, you mention you'd like to know how

...computing how covariate data will reduce the MDE and/or sample size in an experiment.

If the covariates you select are predictive of the outcome, then adjusting for them in the analysis will reduce variance, as you mention.  The easiest way to estimate this might be to take pre-experiment data, run a regression of those covariates on the outcome, and estimate $\sigma_{y\mid X}$ from that regression.  While this does not estimate the degree to which the variance is reduced, it estimates the reduced variance.
Then, once you have an estimate of the residual variance, use that in the equation for $\gamma$ above to determine what power you might have.
